# script for output which having same name as directory

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I am trying to write a script in which the output should be named after its parent directory.

Ex:
I have 3 directory named as **2018-10-01, 2018-11-11, 2018-06-05** . In each directory having n number of files.

I run the command as below :

```
for D in */; do wc -l * > response.txt; done
```

I got output in each folder but with the same name ie response.txt.

The thing I want here is that `response.txt` Should be named after its parent directory's name.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to have kind of a "summary file" that contains the line count of all files in each respective directory.

Using shell globs, like you did, it could be realized like this:

```
for directory in */ ; do
    wc -l "$directory"/* > "$directory/$(basename "$directory").txt"
done
```

First, I changed your glob for `wc` to match files inside the respective directory instead of your current folder, as I assume this is what you want to accomplish. Then I compose the target filename by substituting the output of the `basename` command, which returns the last component from the path it gets as argument (e.g. "foo" from "2018-11-16/foo/")

Note however that depending on your shell options, not all files might be matched. By default hidden files (filename starting with a `.`) are ignored, unless you have set the `dotglob` option set with `shopt -s dotglob`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you wanting to do with the "wc -l" since that puts the exact same answer in each response.txt file.  Are you looking to get the number of entries within each directory, and put that into a response.txt file associated with that directory?  If so, try this

```
for D in */; do
  wc -l ${D}/* >${D}-response.txt
done
```

That will loop through each directory, get the total number of items in each directory and store the output in a file that starts with the directory name and ends in "-response.txt"

Hope this helps.

Comment: That won't work, as `${D}` will end with a slash, so that `${D}-response.txt` will be a file "-response.txt" in the respective folder.

Comment: Oops.  Right.  Try "wc -l ${D}/* >${D%/}-response.txt"  The "%/" will remove the trailing /.  Good catch.

Comment: hi used the command ==>> **for D in */; do wc -l ${D}/* > ${D%/}Request;done**  which  is working fine . But in each directory there are two file named as  .CUD and .CUR , I want to read both files separately  . Please suggest .

Comment: @user893815, what do you mean by "read both files separately"?  What do you want to do?  If it is different from the question asked here, I suggest submitting a new question.